# Слишком длинный путь или имя файла

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Нужно опубликовать проект, а возникает ошибка длины пути или имени файла. Все это в VS 2010 Professional.

> Слишком длинный путь или имя файла. Полное имя файла должно содержать меньше 260 знаков, а имя каталога - меньше 248 знаков.

Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, как вариант, использовать [subst](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst).
Или, если софт это поддерживает, то UNC путь `\\?\c:\path\to\project`. В этом случае ограничение составит [32767 символов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath).

Answer (score 0):

Глобально (независимо от типа использованного языка) - изменить текущий каталог в несколько итераций на нужный Вам, а потом из него уже открыть файл.

Comment: Неправильно понят вопрос, мне нужно опубликовать узел, а он не публикуется из-за такой вот ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить эту проблему путём добавления в файл настройки публикации по адресу `<Папка проекта>\Properties\PublishProfiles\<Имя публикации>.pubxml` следующей директивы:

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>..\Temp\</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

внутри директивы `<PropertyGroup>`.

Суть идеи, как я понял, заключается в том, чтобы сократить путь на который ругается компилятор. Так что имеет смысл в директиве указать путь как можно ближе к корню.
Опробовано на VS2017, но должно работать и на более старых.